# Polluting a class's environment

Tags: python, oop

I have an object that holds lots of ids that are accessed statically. I want to split that up into another object which holds only those ids without the need of making modifications to the already existen code base. Take for example:

```
class _CarType(object):
    DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE = 0
    GAS_CAR_ENGINE = 1 # lots of these ids

class Car(object):
    types = _CarType
```

I want to be able to access `_CarType.DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE` either by calling `Car.types.DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE`, either by `Car.DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE` for backwards compatibility with the existent code. It's clear that I cannot use `__getattr__` so I am trying to find a way of making this work (maybe metaclasses ? )

Comment: why you can not use `__getattr__`? Seems like the easiest solution here.
(check for isupper and do `getattr(_CarType, key)`)

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not exactly what subclassing is made for, it accomplishes what you describe:

```
class _CarType(object):
    DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE = 0
    GAS_CAR_ENGINE = 1 # lots of these ids

class Car(_CarType):
    types = _CarType
```

Comment: Thnaks balpha for your answer, but I tend to not prefer it because I forgot to mention that Car will subclass some other class and I am not very fond of multiple inheritance. But this is a good idea, nevertheless!

Comment: Multiple inheritance should not pose a problem in this case -- as long as `_CarType` only contains your constants, and they don't appear anywhere else, I don't see a risk for any MRO head scratching.

Comment: Actually answers the question, unlike my attempt, and this looks like the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
class Car(object):
    for attr, value in _CarType.__dict__.items():
        it not attr.startswith('_'):
            locals()[attr] = value
    del attr, value
```

Or you can do it out of the class declaration:

```
class Car(object):
    # snip

for attr, value in _CarType.__dict__.items():
    it not attr.startswith('_'):
        setattr(Car, attr, value)
del attr, value
```

Comment: It works very well, but I am looking for a more elegant solution. If nothing comes up, you are the winner! Thank you very much.

Comment: You should not modify `locals()`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: This use of setattr is about the most elegant and simple solution you're going to get.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do this with a metaclass:

```
class _CarType(type):
    DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE = 0
    GAS_CAR_ENGINE = 1 # lots of these ids
    def __init__(self,name,bases,dct):
        for key in dir(_CarType):
            if key.isupper():
                setattr(self,key,getattr(_CarType,key))

class Car(object):
    __metaclass__=_CarType

print(Car.DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE)
print(Car.GAS_CAR_ENGINE)
```

Comment: I agree that simpler is better than complex, and metaclasses aren't really needed here.
However, as one trying to understand metaclasses, I hope this might be useful to others going down the same road.

Answer (score 2):

Your options fall into two substantial categories: you either copy the attributes from `_CarType` into `Car`, or set `Car`'s metaclass to a custom one with a `__getattr__` method that delegates to `_CarType` (so it isn't exactly true that you can't use `__getattr__`: you can, you just need to put in in `Car`'s **meta**class rather than in `Car` itself;-).

The second choice has implications that you might find peculiar (unless they are specifically desired): the attributes don't show up on `dir(Car)`, *and* they can't be accessed on an **instance** of `Car`, only on `Car` itself.  I.e.:

```
>>> class MetaGetattr(type):
...   def __getattr__(cls, nm):
...     return getattr(cls.types, nm)
... 
>>> class Car:
...   __metaclass__ = MetaGetattr
...   types = _CarType
... 
>>> Car.GAS_CAR_ENGINE
1
>>> Car().GAS_CAR_ENGINE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'GAS_CAR_ENGINE'
```

You could fix the "not from an instance" issue by *also* adding a `__getattr__` to `Car`:

```
>>> class Car:
...   __metaclass__ = MetaGetattr
...   types = _CarType
...   def __getattr__(self, nm):
...     return getattr(self.types, nm)
...
```

to make both kinds of lookup work, as is probably expected:

```
>>> Car.GAS_CAR_ENGINE
1
>>> Car().GAS_CAR_ENGINE
1
```

However, defining **two**, essentially-equal `__getattr__`s, doesn't seem elegant.

So I suspect that the simpler approach, "copy all attributes", is preferable.  In Python 2.6 or better, this is an obvious candidate for a class decorator:

```
def typesfrom(typesclass):
  def decorate(cls):
    cls.types = typesclass
    for n in dir(typesclass):
      if n[0] == '_': continue
      v = getattr(typesclass, n)
      setattr(cls, n, v)
    return cls
  return decorate

@typesfrom(_CarType)
class Car(object):
  pass
```

In general, it's worth defining a decorator if you're using it more than once; if you only need to perform this task for one class ever, then expanding the code inline instead (after the `class` statement) may be better.

If you're stuck with Python 2.5 (or even 2.4), you can still define `typesfrom` the same way, you just apply it in a slightly less elegant matter, i.e., the `Car` definition becomes:

```
class Car(object):
  pass
Car = typesfrom(_CarType)(Car)
```

Do remember decorator syntax (introduced in 2.2 for functions, in 2.6 for classes) is just a handy way to wrap these important and frequently recurring semantics.

Answer (score 0):

```
class _CarType(object):
    DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE = 0
    GAS_CAR_ENGINE = 1 # lots of these ids

class Car:
  types = _CarType
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.types, name)
```

If an attribute of an object is not found, and it defines that magic method `__getattr__`, that gets called to try to find it.

Only works on a Car instance, not on the class.

Comment: Have you even try this solution ? How would Car.DIESEL_CAR_ENGINE work? self refers to an already created object ...

Comment: Oops, it was supposed to... fixed the bugs.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to access the types in a static manner, so your solution doesn't work ... that's why I even specified that __getattr__ won't work for me.

Comment: Ah, yep.  I wouldn't call that 'access the types in a static manner', I think the normal way to say that would be 'access the types through the class'.  Anyway, I didn't get quite what you were trying to do...